# What is the best statistical test to compare mortality rates between 2 groups?

Tags: binary-data, mortality

I want to compare the mortality rates of 2 groups (control vs treatment). 
I have binary data (1 = Alive ; 0 = Dead) which gives me a mortality rate (%). 
What is the best way to compare these 2 groups and see if there is a significant difference between them?

Comment: Are all followed for the same time (i.e. no censoring)? If not all for the same time, do you know the observation time for each individual or the group?  Were the groups created by randomization or somehow created in a different way?

Comment: I'm looking at the effect of an increase of ambient temperature on the survival of an insect. 
I look at how many die before reaching their adult stage for the 2 treatments (hot vs cold). The groups are followed for the same time (until they reach the adult stage).
I want to see if there is a significant difference in mortality between each treatment but I'm unsure as to how to do this.

Answer (score -1):

I believe [McNemar's test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McNemar%27s_test#Information_in_the_pairings) is what you're looking for